# Change button to link in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have buttons in my html table. When I click on button I want to change link button to "Un-Extend" and I click on "Un-Extend" switch back previous button. How can I do that?
[image]

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>
              @item.MemberCustomerName
           </td>
           <td>
             @item.PositionCodeDescription
           </td>
           <td>
             @item.MemberMasterCustomer
           </td>
           <td>
             @item.MemberCustomerEmail
           </td>
           <td>
             @if (item.EndDate != null)
             {
                  @item.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
             }
           </td>
           <td>
                <button id="btnExtend" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveExtend" data-value='"@item.CommitteeMasterCustomer"'>Extend</button>
            </td>
         </tr>

        }
```

Comment: Love this comment

Comment: lol . with singing poem

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this.

```
<button id="btnExtend" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs un-extended" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveExtend" data-value='"@item.CommitteeMasterCustomer"'>Extend</button>

    jQuery(document).on("click",".un-extended",function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("extend")){
            $(this).addClass("extend");
            $(this).text("Un-Extend");
        }else{
           $(this).removeClass("extend");
            $(this).text("Extend");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzvqonm/)**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Extend") {
        $(this).text('Un-Extend');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Extend');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean change the `button` tag to `a` tag?

As the button elements are inside the loop iteration, you can't use the same `ID(s)` name, instead put classname `btnExtend`*(you name it)*, and register click handler for its, like following :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btnExtend', function() {
  $(this).text(($(this).text() == 'Extend' ? 'Un-Extended' : 'Extend'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnExtend" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btnExtend" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveExtend" data-value='"@item.CommitteeMasterCustomer"'>Extend</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

$("#btnExtend").on("click",function(){

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Extend' ? 'Un-Extend': 'Extend');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Change into below code and apply below funion of jquery into code:

```html
tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>
              @item.MemberCustomerName
           </td>
           <td>
             @item.PositionCodeDescription
           </td>
           <td>
             @item.MemberMasterCustomer
           </td>
           <td>
             @item.MemberCustomerEmail
           </td>
           <td>
             @if (item.EndDate != null)
             {
                  @item.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
             }
           </td>
           <td>
                <button id="btnExtend" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveExtend" data-value='"@item.CommitteeMasterCustomer"' onclick ="showhide(this);" >Extend</button>
            </td>
         </tr>

        }
```

```html
<script>  function showhide(victim)
    {
        var text = $(victim).closest('td').find('input:button').text();

        if (text == "Extend") {
            $(victim).closest('td').find('input:button').text('Un-Extend');
        }
        else {
            $(victim).closest('td').find('input:button').text('Extend');
        }

    } </script>
```